# A good thread pool queue size

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

Ok , let's assume we have a thread pool with a "kind of" dynamic flat container, which has a max capacity of x since the memory is on the stack to improve performance.

in minimal code (I don't want to get to specific):

```
template <int32 QSIZE, int32 PSIZE> class ThreadPool
{
public:
ThreadPool()
{
    for (int32 i = 0; PSIZE > i; ++i)
    {
        m_Workers.push(Thread(thread_main, m_Queue, m_Signal, m_IsRunning));
    }
}

~ThreadPool()
{
    //Wait and destroy all threads
}

void run(Task task)
{
    m_Queue.push(task);
    m_Signal.wake_all();
}

private:
    FlatVector<Thread, PSIZE> m_Workers; //PSIZE --> max capacity
    FlatQueue<Task, QSIZE>    m_Queue; //QSIZE --> max capacity
    ConditionVariable         m_Signal;
    AtomicBool                m_IsRunning;
};
```

the `class Task` is an implementation for an inplace function with bound parameters and move semantic.

The `FlatVector` is a vector with memory on the stack and a max capacity of `PSIZE` (pool size).

the `FlatQueue` is basically the same construct as a queue with a capacity of `QSIZE` (queue size)

One `Task` has a maximum size of 512 bit.

Is there a good rule of thumb how large a thread pool task queue should grow in the worst case? (If possible with consideration of the given example, if not possible a guess on regular thread pools is fine as well.)

In the most cases my pool is running with 8 threads since that's my core count and the application which is using the pool can take a decent advantage of a higher thread count. (It's a simple physic simulation)

Would it be a better way to package tasks together into task bundles (As long as they wouldn't exceed the 512 bit together, considering this example.) or should I just skip the calculation which can't be placed in this frame anymore and calculate them in the next one? The physical calculation will be calculated for 2 frames then.

Usualy I am choosing a queue size something between 64 - 128 tasks which is fine (at least performance wise) but actually it feels like 128 tasks in a pool at the same time are a bit much to me and I don't want to waste this amount of memory.

Sometimes I am exceeding the limit of 64 tasks in the pool at the same time if I set the pool under high load. (that's why I decided to increase the pool size in the first place.)

Adding a single 512 bit task (worst case) to my pool takes something between 1,02 and 1,3 e power(-7) seconds on my system.

Doing the same with a "regular" thread pool and "regular" function bindings with heap allocation and move semantic takes something between 1.8 - 2.3 e power(-5) seconds, what shows there is a real benefit in using the stack in this case.

Comment: Writing your own threadpool class is a lot like writing your own string class.  Kinda important that you do this at least once in your life, perhaps, but it is just as important to compare what you did with what other programmers did.  Only *that* provides insight.  When you do, you'll end up eliminating PSIZE, since its optimal value is a runtime detail that depends on the specific machine your code runs on.  And you'll be very likely to eliminate QSIZE as well since there is no decent way to guess at the value up front and to handle exceeding that limit.  Compare, it is important.

Comment: Fair point, I know that a pool (usually) should have a size of cpu cores. Later on at least the thread count will be replaced (that's where you are right) with a getCoreCount() function at runtime. Nevertheless, the stack container with the QSIZE will stay, since the performance benefit of the stack container is to strong. Actually I am already handling the overflows in a manner I don't like to much: If the queue is full, I execute them on the mainthread. That's something I would like to avoid in the future, that's why I am looking for a better solution which runs more parallel.

Answer (score 1):

A general answer to the question:

For a workload that runs constantly without waiting on other resources, logically, the maximum number of threads should be the same as the number of physical processors (or twice that if the processor has hyper-threading).

For a workload that waits on other resources (e.g. waiting for a socket to connect), you will want to compensate for this latency to get maximum throughput, by having more threads than logical processors (dependent on your wait time). Hundreds of threads would be fine if most are blocked. You might consider separating out the latency bound portion of the task and the CPU intensive part of the task to fully load balance the workload each having a different thread count.

You could empirically determine your optimum thread count assuming you want to maximise throughput.

An interesting solution to software self tuning the thread count could be achieved by using control theory. The book Feedback Control for Computer Systems by Philipp K. Janert is a good reference on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good rule of thumb how large a thread pool task queue should grow in the worst case?

I think the right questions to ask are:

- How long can a task wait before being evaluated?
- Does a new task of a particular type supercede an existing task?